# Have strange noise in compositor in Cycles (Cycles X too)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, noise-reduction

I make render of smoke in cycles in blender 3.0.
Render location in eevee and mix it in copmositor. BUT in render a have no noise and have it in copositor.

How I can fix it? Files in attach - blendfile with smoke domain, 1 frame of location, two frame os smoke. In compositor I use alpha over with convert primul. What is this?)))
https://yadi.sk/d/T4U6HcmQyUYjUg - attach (file cant upload in storage, i dont know why.)

[image: trouble on the pic]

Comment: Blender 3.0 is not officially released until December so it's quite possible that the issue you're seeing will be fixed before then.

Comment: In Cycles 293 it have too -_-

Comment: Someone more familiar with the compositor is going to have to answer that one, but no-one is going to install a program just so that they can download and view your Blend file! Please upload it to an official site. [How to upload a Blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help).

Comment: I try, but file (1mb) doesnt upload. I dnot know, whe - I rasterted and reload, but progress it 0%

Comment: Your blend file is for Blender 3.0 and has a lot of linked data that is all missing. Also, Blender 2.93 almost freezes when you open this file.

Comment: I fixed this. Just up samples in render to 512.